# Is there a way to put a div behind the other?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For my project I'd like to use a footer wich is directly after the main row. The main row should have the same border radius like the footer. At the moment the footer covers a part of the main row.
My current HTML code:

```
<div class="row main">
    <aside class="col-lg-1">
        [...]
    </aside>
    <main class="col-lg-11">
        <h1>
            Have a nice day!
        </h1>
        <p>
            [...]
        </p>
    </main>
    <aside>
        [...]
    </aside>
</div>
<footer class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            [...]
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
.main {
    border-bottom-left-radius: @border-radius-large*6;
    border-bottom-right-radius: @border-radius-large*6;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom-right-radius: @border-radius-large*6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: @border-radius-large*6;
}
```

I'd tried to solve this by using the z-index option, but this didn't work.

THX for your help.

Comment: You need to convert your SASS/LESS to regular CSS if you want help from  those of us who don't use that.

Comment: The @ sign is only a variable that allows you to put a standard for the radius. That means: border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having `margin-bottom:-60px` in class `main`. Remove it and your `footer` will stay right after your main row.
**EDIT**
With your comment below, i think i see your problem, so instead remove `margin-bottom` in your class `main`, you change the value of `padding-bottom` in `main` from `10px` to `60px`
P/S: If you want to increase the space between your last `aside` with `footer`, increase your `padding-bottom` in your `main`

Comment: But when I remove margin then I've a straight line between the .main and footer. What I want to get, is a border-radius where the footer is behind - that means the backgroundcolor of the footer should fill the free space. IÄm sorry, I'm not allowed to add images because of reputation. THX

Comment: @andi-g ok so what you want next? borders between `main` and `footer` disapper or else? and give me your css of `@border-radius-large*6` so i can have a better demo to test

Comment: **border-bottom-left-radius:** 60px; and also **border-bottom-left-radius:** 60px;  If you put this to .main there is a space between .main and footer. So I'd like to fill the gaps betwen .main and footer with the background-color of footer.

Comment: @andi-g check again my answer and see if it help you solve your problem